# combination of numbers for given number(n*n-1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a combination of number, how to achieve this in JavaScript

example

```
input:

123

Output(n*(n-1) combinations)
123
132
213
231
321
312
```

the given number is anything, how to achieve in short way?

Comment: Technically, what you're looking for is [permutations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript) instead of [combinations](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array)

Comment: Have you tried converting that formula into javascript?